# Pnpm for pre-commit custom hook

Tags: svelte, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pnpm, pre-commit.com

I work on a `python/svelte` full-stack app where we use `pre-commit`. I've installed `stylelint` to frontend `web` dir and configured a custom hook for it :

```yaml
- id: stylelint
        name: stylelint
        additional_dependencies:
          - stylelint
        entry: pnpm run --dir web lint:scss
        files: ^.*\.(css|scss|svelte)$
        language: node
        pass_filenames: false
```

And the problem is: our `web` folder is managed by `pnpm`, but `language: node` will install dependencies with `npm`, and hook not gonna work.

The question is: how could I tell to `pre-commit` to use `pnpm` overall and install the `stylelint` with `pnpm add -D stylelint`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pre-commit works best when it manages the installed tools -- without that your contributors will have to set up every tool themselves and make sure that versions are synchronized and correct (which is one of the primary goals of the tool)

pre-commit also works best when it manages the files that are sent to tools -- that way it can control whether the correct files are sent or not (especially during the various workflow stages and when conflicts arise)

what you're doing *should already work* -- however it's doing extra work and is in the unsupported pathway.  the extra work here is `language: node` -- where it is setting up a node environment and then ~essentially discarding it because you're executing `pnpm`

you can use [`repo: local`](https://pre-commit.com/#repository-local-hooks) hooks with [`language: system`](https://pre-commit.com/#system) which will just run the tools that are on your `$PATH`.  note that both of these suffer from the issues above and are provided as an unsupported escape hatch from the right way to do things.  adjusting your config you'd remove `additional_dependencies` and adjust `language` accordingly

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit